# How to rewrite LINQ Any() to make it suitable for .NET 3.5

Tags: linq, asp.net-3.5, any

I have the following **EF** class:

```
class Product
{
   public int ProdId { get; set; }
   public int ProdDesc { get; set; }
   public int ProdKeywords { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have to implement a search function that looks at `ProdDesc` and `ProdKeywords`. The keywords are registered in a `array` and the collection of products in a `IQueryable`

```
string[] keywordsArray = new string[] {"kw1", "kw2", ..., "kwN"};

IQueryable<Product> products = repository.GetProducts();
```

To see if there are products matching the keywords I use the following **LINQ**:

```
var matchingProducts = products.Where(p => keywordsArray.Any(k => p.ProdDesc.Contains(k) ||
                                                                  p.ProdKeywords.Contains(k));
```

which works like a charm in .NET 4.

The **BIG** problem is that I am forced to use this code in **.NET 3.5** and I just discovered that `Any` and `Contains` (the LINQ method, not the one applied to strings) don't work in that framework. That's a real pain. The code is too big to rewrite everything and the deadline is too close.

I found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx) really interesting but I can't make it work in my case. Anybody might help?

Comment: I think that you have a problem not with the .NET framework version itself but the EF framework version.

Comment: @BojanSkrchevski, if you look at the article it states that the problem is in the .NET. Probably it is also linked to the EF.

Answer (score 3):

What's about:

```
static class Extension   
{
    public static bool Contains(this IEnumerable<object> source, object value)
    {
        foreach (object o in source)
            if (o.Equals(value)) return true;

        return false;
    }
}


var mylist = keywordsArray.ToList();

matchingProducts = products.Where(p => mylist.Exists(k => p.ProdDesc.Contains(k) ||
                                                          p.ProdKeywords.Contains(k));
```

Comment: your solution is working (although there is a typo with Contains and Exists) but the problem is that you enumerate the object. the same result can be obtained by just placing AsEnumerable() in my code: `var matchingProducts = products.AsEnumerable().Where(...)`

Answer (score 0):

you could query first the any and store that in a enumerable and the check if the count is bigger then 0

Comment: thanks I will try your solution, the problem is that I was aiming in using differed execution and by now I already changed my LINQ code to use enumerable in almost all my queries...